# image pop-up should open on double click

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, magnific-popup

I am using jquery "magnific-popup" jquery plugin and want that image should pop-up on double click instead of single click. I checked documentation but didnt find anything regarding this. Please help me in this.

Answer (score 0):

None of your users are going to expect that to be the behavior because nothing else they work with on the web utilizes double-click. Since it's counter intuitive, you'll need to provide instructions to users on what to do.  You should take this as a sign that you are going about it the wrong way and should follow the normal conventions for web UI.